# Upgrade hot-end to achieve higher temps (e.g. for PETG)

Tags: hotend, petg, wanhao

I'm struggling to get my printer to the temps required for modified PETG (the filament I have is Fillamentum CPE and recommends 255-275 °C), I currently can only reach 245/250 °C even if my target temperature is above that. The hot-end is fully ceramic wrapped and metal (no PTFE liner to worry about) and the printer is in a DIY heat shielded enclosure (non-heated).

The printer is an old (but gold) Wanhao Duplicator 4 (Rep 1 clone) with a MK8/9 extruder running a custom build of Sailfish. I know there is a firmware cap at 280 °C but that's fine, I don't intend to go above that.

Bar totally swapping out the extruder assembly what can I do to up the hot-end temperature, upgrade the power supply, heater cartridge?

Comment: What PETG do you have that recommends 255-275? Typical recommended range for PETG is 220-250 °C, though I'd say the minimum is more like 230 or 235. Have you tried printing it at temperatures you can reach and had problems that you think would be resolved by using a higher temperature? In my experience even at 250 PETG is a dripping mess.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you want to upgrade the extruder if your hotend can reach higher temperatures. Try going at 260°C and check the print speed, which you haven't mentioned. Maybe you are printing too fast for that temperature+nozzle (which is also not mentioned). Usually printing at the low-end of the temperature range involves slowing down further (and PETG is not fast to begin with).

Comment: @FarO I cannot reach higher temperatures, that is the issue. It doesn’t matter what my max temperature is, if it’s above 245/250 it will never reach it.

Comment: Are you sure the firmware limit is at 280 °C? A hotend should get hotter than 250 °C when heated static (no filament to cool it down).

Comment: @0scar Positive, I’ve seen it written in the firmware plus on occasion it does fluctuate up to 251/2~. Before the enclosure and the ceramic wrap I couldn’t even maintain 230~. It’s a very old printer, my guess was the power supply or heating cartridge isn’t spec’d to go that high, but I’m unsure.

Comment: Well if the hotend should reach higher, but it doesn't, I would surely measure the voltage of the PSU under load (that means, when the hotend and bed are cold and you turn on both to reach 250/80 C).

Comment: @FarO That makes sense, I’ll give that a try. I know the max temp as per the print spec is 280 so I think I should be hitting a little higher than I am. I’m not sure the heater cartridges are supposed to go that high, but from looking online it seems most 40/50W cartridges heat to around 300.

Comment: Are you sure you have a 24V PSU?

Comment: @FarO I am, it’s the stock power supply with the printer. 24V 14.6A

Answer (score 1):

Most PETG reacts vey badly to temperatures above 255. The typical optimal PETG temperature ranges from 225 to 245. Above that it gets sticky...

If PETG is your goal, you might want to find a filament that is more friendly to your printer. They are pretty cheap, and now you have transitioned to an all-metal hot end, you should be good to go!

Comment: Its a modified PETG, the brand is Fillamentum and the temp range 255-275 is recommended by the brand. I have a few reels of it so I’m determined to print with it. Getting major inconsistent and under extrusion at 245.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the hot-end in silicone?

Comment: Hot-end is already wrapped in ceramic, which I believe has much better thermal insulation properties than silicone.

Comment: I’m assuming that you have turned-off any cooling fans?

Comment: Correct, the extruded fan is on to stabilise the temperature but I have no control over this. Weirdly it does seem to be on quite aggressively considering it’s not even at the target temperature.

Comment: An extra layer of silicone might help buy you a few degrees - the ceramic coatings are often rather thin... I use self sealing tape and my head is also ceramic-coated - just be careful about the max temp it can handle. Are you using an infrared thermometer to measure temperature?

Comment: Upgrading the heater will not only require more power, but probably a new mainboard to in order to handle that power without catching fire. Are you experienced in electronics?

Comment: Fairly, I’ve wired in the cooling fan (as it doesn’t come as standard) into the motherboard and an auto levelling sensor.

Comment: This would be MUCH more dangerous: unless you can find a kit specifically for your machine, you would potentially need to do major surgery to the mainboard to re-route power and potentially replace power transistors and the like... It is not as simple as wiring in a fan! (The hot-end control circuitry and software is the core of any 3D printer.)

Comment: Loads can be easily taken from the board with an external MOSFET module, but that is rarely necessary for hotend heater elements. The current is determined by the resistance of the heater element.

Comment: Totally agree about the external MOSFET - that is what I meant by re-routing power. My concern here is that many of the cheaper mainboards are not engineered to handle higher current draws and/or higher voltages than their original configuration. The worst offenders have been known to spontaneously combust even when operated within their default spec. Now, obviously if you know how to rate the existing mainboard power drive capabilities you are ok to go for a higher power heater - but otherwise you run the risk of overloading things unless you resort to off-board/uprated components.